# 301 redirects in htaccess dont acknowledge query strings

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

I need to redirect an old dynamic page to a new keyword-url one:

```
Redirect 301 http://www.domain.com/index.php?id=100 http://www.domain.com/newhello
```

However, I keep getting a 404 error:

> The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.

It is as if apache is ignoring the query string and only looking at the 'index.php' part of the URL.

I've played around with 'RewriteRule' and 'RedirectMatch 301' too but have the same result. Any advice would be appreciated.

EDIT - below is a paste of the entire .htaccess file's contents. Note this is in the root directory:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !newroot/
RewriteRule (.*) /newroot/$1 [L]

#successful 301 redirect or mod_rewrite directives will be listed from here.
```

Comment: What are your `mod_rewrite` rules?

Comment: Hi Victory, I'm yet to set up any rules. I've edited the original question to show what my .htaccess file contains at present. Hope this can help you to help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot match QUERY_STRING using `Redirect` directive. Use `mod_rewrite` instead like this in your root .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=100$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.domain.com/newhello? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/newroot/
RewriteRule (.*) /newroot/$1 [L]
```

Comment: thanks for the info anubhava but i'm still getting the same issue. it's as if apache is not seeing this rule as matched and therefore doesn't even look at it. Is there a better way to tell apache to look at the entire URL?

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: yes, verified. the redirects work fine if they are basic (ie static urls). It is only the urls with `?id=123` that are causing problems....

Comment: Above rule is only for `?id=100` Since that is what you showed in your question. Do you want to redirect to `http://www.domain.com/newhello` for any `?id=<any-number>`?

Comment: No, I'm sorry for confusing you. The above rule does not work for `?id=100`. However, if we can get it to work I can apply the same logic to other query string urls.

Comment: That rule definitely works, you need to make sure to place it right as I showed in my most recent edit.

Comment: Great! Working now. Thank you! One final thing - if the QSD flag is not available, what can I use to remove the query string from the new URL?

Comment: You can see how I have added `?` at the end of `newhello?` that is for stripping out existing query string.

Comment: amazing! thank you for your explanations and patience. i've learnt a lot from this conversation!